# Find the sum of the series $1^3 + 3\cdot 2^2 + 3^3 + 3\cdot 4^2 + 5^3 + 3\cdot 6^2...$ up to $n$ terms

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

> Find the sum of first $n$ terms of the series $1^3 + 3\cdot 2^2 + 3^3 + 3\cdot 4^2 + 5^3 + 3\cdot 6^2...$
>
> 1. When $n$ is even.
> 2. When $n$ is odd.

This sum can be written as

$$\sum_{1}^n (2k-1)^{3} +3 \sum_{1}^n (2k)^{2} $$
I can handle the sum up to n terms when it is not specified that $n$ is even or odd. 
In this problem I'm confused, what changes should be done to get sum for even or odd $n$. 
In my textbook, $n$ is replaced by $2m$ and then they solved the problem for first $m$ terms and then substituted  $m = n/2$ and same is done for odd case, by substituting $n=2m-1$. 
I didn't get that solution. 
Any suggestion would be helpful.

Comment: $f(x)=  (2x-1)^3$ is a polynomial thus there is a unique polynomial such that $g(x)-g(x-1) =f(x),g(0) =0$ so that $\sum_{k=1}^n f(k) = g(n)$ and your sum is $\sum_{k=1}^n f(k)+3f(k+1/2) = g(n)+3g(n+1/2)-3g(1/2)$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**HINT**

When $n = 2m$ is even, both sums have the same amount of terms, $n/2 = m$ each.
When $n = 2m-1$ is odd, the left sum has one more term than the right, so there must be $m$ terms in the left and $m-1$ in the right.

Also notice that the even $n$ sum and the odd $n$ sum are different by just one last term in the right sum.

Answer (score 1):

Details for your comment above:

$n$ is even:
$$\sum_{1}^{n/2} (2k-1)^{3} +3 \sum_{1}^{n/2} (2k)^{2}$$
Example:
$$1^3 + 3\cdot 2^2 = \sum_{k=1}^{2/2}(2k-1)^3+3\sum_{k=1}^{2/2}(2k)^2$$
$n$ is odd:
$$\sum_{1}^{(n+1)/2} (2k-1)^{3} +3 \sum_{1}^{(n+1)/2-1} (2k)^{2}$$
Example:
$$1^3 + 3\cdot 2^2 + 3^3 = \sum_{k=1}^{(3+1)/2}(2k-1)^3+3\sum_{k=1}^{(3+1)/2-1}(2k)^2$$

Comment: This was my actual confusion. I got it now. Thanks.

Comment: You are welcome! Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Its a hint

Split the series to two. One is sum of cubic of odd.  And other one is 3*(sum of square of even )